# C language: check if scanf user input is integer only

Tags: c

So i need to get `number` from user and i want to check if the `number` is int:

```
char temp;
int num;
int res = scanf("%d%c", &num, &temp);
if (res == 2)
{

}
else
{

}
```

The problem is that even if the `input` is `double` for example `2.2` the if executed.
I also try this:

```
int n = atoi(&temp);
```

Comment: Please check return value of `scanf`

Comment: The input is the **string** `2.2`. It's neither double nor integer. Its "meaning" is whatever you give it. `scanf` is not wrong to take `2` and `.` out of it. It's a valid sequence of characters for the meaning you specified. Such is the nature of parsing without look-ahead.

Comment: So what i can do ?

Comment: `if (res == 2 && isspace(temp))` should do the job.

Comment: What are you expecting when the user types `2.2`?

Comment: Because this is not int i want to print error so it will go to the else section

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is difficult to use if you want a very strict validation of the input typed by the user.

Instead you could you use `getc` to read the input char-by-char and do the validation and value calculation yourself.

Another approach could be `fgets` combined with `sscanf`. That could be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 8

int main(void) {
  char str[MAX_LEN];
  int d, n;

  int flag = 0;                    // Assume it isn't an int

  if (fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin))  // Read into str
  {
    size_t l = strlen(str);
    if (l > 0)                     // Check that we did read something
    {
      if (str[l-1] == '\n')        // Last char must be new line
      {
        if (sscanf(str,"%d%n", &d, &n) == 1)  // Try to scan the str into an int
        {
          if (n == l-1)            // Check that all chars was used
          {
            flag = 1;              // It is an int so set the flag
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (flag)
  {
    printf("%d\n", d);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Not an int\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```